# User.find is not a function mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm getting a `User.find is not a function` error. I believe I've set up everything correctly but apparently not.

Here is my model as well as other pieces of code.

user model

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema)
module.exports.User = User
```

users routes

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const User = require('../models/user')

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  User.find()
    .then(function(users) {
      res.status(201).json(users)
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err)
      res.status(500).send('Eorror ' + err)
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

app.js

```js
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// connect database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/<removed>', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true
});
console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);

// import routes
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

When I run the app I'm getting a ready state of 2 so it is connecting. So not sure where I'm going wrong.

I am trying to keep the db connection to one file where the whole app can use the DB where needed. This part is just for the API so views etc aren't important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code, it will help you

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let userSchema = Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true  
}, {
        versionKey: false
    });
module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're requiring your model in the wrong way. Because you export it like this:

```
module.exports.User = User
```

So you need to require it in this way:

```
const { User } = require('../models/user')
```

Answer (score 0):

I user model export like as bellow

```
module.exports = User;
```